# Issues while using USB Datacards with Beaglebone black (BBB) Hw/Software- Linux

Tags: linux, usb, linux-kernel, beaglebone, usb-data-card

I am trying to connect a USB Data card (intex dc21.6hwm) to Beagle Bone Black(BBB) with Linux kernel (Ver: 3.8.11). Un-fortunately the datacard didn't respond/ failed to power-Up upon plug-in. The issue repeated with other data cards as well. No Usb Activity captured on lsusb & dmesg. So far hauwei datacard is the only working plug & play model identified. What can be the issue with other datacards. Any debug points/suggestions will be highly helpfull.

Thanks,
Vivek.T.

Comment: I see you're new here, per [/help/behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) you don't have to use a signature.
Regarding your question: 3G/4G cellular modems usually have high power requirements. Do you have sufficient power supply? Have you checked BBB's usb ports are not current limited?

Comment: Hi trogper, Thanks for the quick response. so far i m using power adapter specified by the BBB. 1. what can be the minimum power requirement for 3G/4G Modems? 2. As of now, I m not aware of BBB's usb ports current limitations, can you gave vague idea regarding where can i get relevant information on this? Thanks!

Comment: That kernel is very very very old. Please try this with an up to date kernel. The official Debian images come with newer kernels.

Comment: Hi TBR, Upon suggestion taken latest kernel(4.14) from BB. Compiled and flashed on board, Still not able to detect datacards. Thanks!